# Most efficient way to connect dots on a surface without lines crossing?

Tags: geometry

I've recently been designing an electrical circuit. As this a more general, mathematical problem, I'm going to ask it on the math exchange forum:

Let's assume I've got a rectangular plate. On this plate there is a number of x * y transistors. They are stuck within the plate, so that their head is on one and the connectors on the other side of the plate.
Each transistor has one + connector and one - connector. From the side one transistor would look like this: [image]

If you look at the plate from the bottom, you'll therefore see something like this (+ side in green, - side in red, 3 * 5 transistors):[image]

My problem is now the following: Each output needs to be connected to all inputs but that of his own transistor (with a little part in between, but that's not important for the problem).
The lines used to connect them can have any kind of shape, but they aren't allowed to cross each other because this would cause electrical interference.

I'm quite certain that it's not even possible to do so on one surface (or is it?). Therefore I will be extending the contacts of the transistors and put them through more plates, so that I can create a stack looking like this:

[image]

This allows to have independent wiring in the gaps between each layer to achieve the goal of connecting each output to each other input once.

My questions are the following:

1. What is the most efficient way to wire one layer to have as many connections as possible if I have x * y transistors?
2. How do I calculate how many layers I do need in total?